# Refused to load the image because it violates Content policy

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, content-security-policy, webpack-5

I've been stuck with this for days and finally decided to ask out. I've read dozens of issues, pages here but none of them solved my problem. I have an application built on top of this boilerplate: https://github.com/codesbiome/electron-react-webpack-typescript-2022 (the boilerplate isn't important as much, but there are some webpack configs there). I've read the documentation and it says that I should define a protocol for rendering images in this case, like this

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('atom', (request, callback) => {
    const filePath = url.fileURLToPath(
      'file://' + request.url.slice('atom://'.length),
    );
    callback(filePath);
  });
});
```

This responds with an error "refused to load resource", even with content security policy set like this:

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
      worker-src atom:; 
      child-src atom: gap:;
      img-src 'self' atom: data:;
      default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:"
    />
```

If I change *atom* to something like *blob* or *file* it errors with "it is not allowed to load resource".
I'm rendering it inside react, like this

```
const image_path = `atom://${image.path}`;
<img src={image_path} />
```

Turning off security doesn't work, and even if it did I don't find it as an acceptable answer. I'm trying to read the file off of the local machine and I've looked up how some other applications that use electron are doing it (by uploading it to their  servers). But I'm still wondering if something like this was even possible without an additional server as I want the app to work offline. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea why you'd need this when you're using electron. It does not have CSP enforcement out of the box. Sounds like that boilerplate _is_ important, because when set up manually, Electron absolutely doesn't need this. Might even be time to ask on their issue tracker? (after digging a bit deeper, of course)

Comment: I want to have a preview of the images before processing them

Comment: Then it's time to show a true [mcve], because just this is not enough code to suggest anything's going wrong other than that boilerplate.

Comment: The error definitely lies somewhere in the  boilerplate, I've just made an app with example on the  electron website and it loads images perfectly fine. That means I'll have to open an issue. Thank you for your time.